# Execute program from TSQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, windows, shell, t-sql

We are using Service Broker with a queue activation stored procedure. This receives events such as Employee Hired/Fired/LocationChanged. We wish to invoke shell scripts to update Active Directory appropriately.

Is there a direct way of calling a windows program with parameters from a stored procedure? I realize we could use a CLR solution if no other method is possible.

Comment: Instead, I would probably have a custom AD-Update WIndows service, which monitored a particular set of tables for such updates and updated AD accordingly.

Comment: Probably best to create a SQL Agent job written in Powershell, and call it using `sp_start_job`

Comment: You can use xp_cmdshell for shell commands, but it's usually a bad idea because you can easily deadlock yourself if you do too much from triggers and broker stuff. Just put the message into some table and execute an agent job that processes the messages asynchroniously

Comment: A little addition to my answer. A Job might not be the best thing after all, because broker generates new messages in async mode, but you can only run one job at a time. Executing a new agent job while one is currently running might lead to errors and rollbacks which has own issues. Perhaps it's enough to have a job that runs every X  minutes and process newly added stuff instead

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. We have decided to invoke a remote Powershell script from a CLR procedure. To minimize deadlocks we have moved the message to its own unique queue and service. The events will be processed synchronously with a timeout. The use of a dedicated CLR function is to avoid the security hole presented by the use of PS_Shell.

Comment: In addition, the use of a synchronous script execution is that we may rerun multiple messages following an outage of the Active Directory server. Asynchronous execution would overwhelm that server.